# vbscript selecting different rows in a xlsx file for range command

Tags: excel, vbscript, range, row

I wrote a vbscript to save a specific range of an xlsx file to a csv file. 
I want to select different columns that are not located next to each other. The range of each column shall contain the last line with Content of it (Range`("F6").End(xlToRight)`).
My code:

```
Public Sub xlsToCsv()    
    Const WorkingDir = "C:\"
    Const xlCSV = 6

    Dim fso, SaveName, myFile
    Dim objExcel, objWorkbook, sheet

    myFile = "test.xlsx"
    SaveName = "test.csv"

    With CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
        If Not .FileExists(WorkingDir & myFile) Then
            MsgBox "File not found:" & vbCrLf & WorkingDir & myFile, vbInformation, "Script Cancelled"
            WScript.Quit
        End If
    End With
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    objExcel.Visible = False
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(WorkingDir & myFile)

    With objWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            .Range("D87", .Range("D87").End(-4121)).Copy
             objWorkbook.Sheets.Add().paste
            .Range("E87", .Range("E87").End(-4121)).Copy
    End With

    set sheet =  objWorkbook.Sheets.Add()
    sheet.paste
    objWorkbook.SaveAs WorkingDir & SaveName, 23
    objWorkbook.Saved = true
    objWorkbook.Close

    Set objWorkbook = Nothing
    Set objExcel = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set myFolder = Nothing
End Sub

call xlsToCsv()
```

I get a type conflict in line 18 code 800A000D with 'Range'. 
How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

2 things here:

- Whenever you use the Range object `Range("F6").End(xlToRight)`, you need to mention its type/parent object. So, in your case, this should be replaced with `objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("F6").End(xlToRight)`
- VBScript does not know the meaning of `xlToRight`. So, you have to use the value of xlToRight which is `-4161` as shown below:

**Replace the following code:**

```
objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("F6", Range("F6").End(xlToRight)).Copy
objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C6", Range("C6").End(xlToRight)).Copy
```

**WITH**

```
 With objWorkbook.Sheets(1)
     .Range("F6", .Range("F6").End(-4161)).Copy
     .Range("C6", .Range("C6").End(-4161)).Copy
 End With
```

Comment: this gives me the horizontal F6 this is the line. i need the column!

Comment: @nolags that is happening because first you copy the F6 range and then you copy the C6 range which overwrites the previously copied F6 range. And when you perform the paste operation, you are only left with the most recent copy i.e, the C6 range. To avoid this you need to paste F6 before copy-pasting C6

Comment: tried it with "objWorkbook.Sheets.Add().paste" after the ".range("f6", ... ).copy" command but it still doesnt work. what is a working paste comman?

Comment: @nolags Update your question with the updated code pls.

Answer (score 1):

Think some of your code may be missing such as declaration of WorkingDir.
I have explicitly referenced the ranges by adding: With objWorkbook.Sheets(1)

```
    Dim WorkingDir As String

    WorkingDir = "C:\test.xlsx"

    Dim fso, FileName, SaveName, myFile
    Dim objExcel, objWorkbook

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
    Set myFile = fso.GetFile(WorkingDir)

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    objExcel.Visible = False
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

    'main operation
    FileName = Left(myFile, InStrRev(myFile, "."))
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(myFile)

    With objWorkbook.Sheets(1)
       .Range("F6", .Range("F6").End(xlToRight)).Copy
       .Range("C6", .Range("C6").End(xlToRight)).Copy
    End With

    Dim sheet: Set sheet = objWorkbook.Sheets.Add()

    sheet.Paste
    SaveName = FileName & "csv"
    objWorkbook.SaveAs SaveName, 23
    objWorkbook.Saved = True
    objWorkbook.Close

    Set objWorkbook = Nothing
    Set objExcel = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
   ' Set myFolder = Nothing
```

Comment: when i save it as .vbs an error in l ine 3 occurs : instructions ending expectet

Comment: You state you are saving as a .csv, also line 3 in code above is only a declaration and will not fail. What is the code at the line where this fails?

Comment: Dim WorkingDir As String

Comment: If you remove the with statement and use fully referenced as follows for both lines does it make a difference?  objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("F6", objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("F6").End(xlToRight)).Copy

Comment: i think ist has a problem with xlToRight

Comment: Yes. That was the additional thing I missed!

Comment: but -4161 gives me the row not the column. what number do i have to insert to get the complete column?

Comment: -4121 ?   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221100(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: okay now i geht only one of the columns i want to add.. how can i add both?